# Are there plans to support Android with Square's Register API

Tags: square-connect

I would like to develop an app that works for both Android and iOS using the Square card reader to integrate with our checkout process.  Are there any plans to support Android in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

The Square Register API is now available for Android. See [this article](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-android/) to get started.